# Java 8 "Missing return type" error for lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am new to Java 8 and trying to understand the concepts. I am getting

```
Missing return type
```

error for the Lambda expression I am passing to `ReadTheFile` method.

### BufferReaderProcessor

```
package java8.programs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface BufferReadderProcessor {
    String process(BufferedReader br) throws IOException;
}
```

### MainJava

```
package java8.programs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MainJava obj = new MainJava();

        String message = obj.ReadTheFIle((BufferedReader br) -> {
                while (br.readLine()!=null)
                    br.readLine();
        });
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public String ReadTheFIle(BufferReadderProcessor bp) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("G:\\DemoJavaFile.txt")));

        return bp.process(br);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed there is no return statement in your lambda body.

Comment: Not only that, you're also performing two `readLine()`s where you mean to only perform one. (You have one in the `while` condition and one in the `while` body.)

Comment: By the way, if `ReadTheFIle` is supposed to offer any benefit, the minimum, it should do, is closing the resource correctly. Then, consider simplifying the construction, i.e. `try( BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("G:\\DemoJavaFile.txt")) ) { return bp.process(br); }`

Comment: Issue is resolved.Thank you All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda expression implements the `BufferReaderProcessor`'s `String process(BufferedReader br)` method, so it should return a `String`.

For example, assuming you wish to return the data you read from the `BufferedReader` :

```
    String message = obj.ReadTheFIle((BufferedReader br) -> {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    });
```

Comment: @khelwood I just fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: or `br.lines().forEachOrdered(sb::append);` or just `obj.ReadTheFIle( br -> br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining()) );`…